Troubleshooting XML Fields Not Showing in Word Document
We need to generate reports that contain repeated information in multiple sections of the document (such as names, dates, etc.). To streamline this process, we're looking to automate the task. The goal is to input the information once, and have it automatically filled in across all relevant sections.
I’ve created an XML file that allows us to achieve this automation. However, when I try to add a new field in the XML, it doesn’t appear in Word as expected. How can we add fields to use in such a report?


Just a thought: could you have you inserted more than one custom xml part with the same uri?

I can add and use all defined fields in my xml file, but when I add or remove fields in the xml it doesn't show up in Word... if that answers your question?

Look at the dropdown underneath "Custom XML Part". Is more than one Part with URI "http://CustomDemoXML.htm" listed? If so, you (or someone) have added another custom XML Part. If so, what you need to do is delete all the Parts with that URI (using VBA) then add the part with the elements that you want.
